# mybatis: update one table accoring to another table

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, mybatis

I want to acheive:
When I click the page, it will update one column in the table 'staffinfo' and then show the table.

and I want to update the column named 'lengthofworking' in table 'staffinfo'. and its value is decided by another table named 'bookingtable'.

Here is the MySQL query:

```
UPDATE crm.staffinfo SET `lengthofworking` = (
  select temp.workinghour from (
    SELECT b.assignedstfid as staffid, SUM(b.duration) as workinghour
    FROM crm.bookingtable b, crm.staffinfo s 
    where s.staffid = b.assignedstfid 
    GROUP BY b.assignedstfid) as temp 
  where temp.staffid = staffinfo.staffid
);
```

which means:
When I want to get the total working hour of a staff, I need to sum up the duration of each booking record related to the staff in table 'bookingtable'.

**I have test this query in MySQL, it works. now I want to implement this query in mybatis.**

Here is what I did:

in Class **Staff.java** :

```
public class Staff {
    private Integer staffid;
    ...
    private Double lengthofworking;
}
```

in Interface **StaffService.java** and Class **StaffServiceImpl.java**:

```
public interface StaffService {

    List<Staff> getAllStaffs();  //  get all the staffs
    ...
    int updateStaffWorkingLength(); //  update the 'length of working' of a staff
}

@Service
public class StaffServiceImpl implements StaffService{

    @Autowired
    private StaffMapper sm;

    @Override
    public List<Staff> getAllStaffs() {
        return sm.getAllStaffs();
    }
    ...
    @Override
    public int updateStaffWorkingLength()  {
        return sm.updateStaffWorkingLength();
    }
}
```

in Interface **StaffMapper.java** :

```
@Mapper
@Repository
public interface StaffMapper {

    List<Staff> getAllStaffs();  //  get all the staffs
    ...
    int updateStaffWorkingLength(); //  update the 'length of working' of a staff

}
```

in **StaffMapper.xml**:

```
...
<mapper namespace="com.crm.mapper.StaffMapper">

    <select id="getAllStaffs" resultType="Staff" >
        select * from crm.staffinfo ;
    </select>
    ...
    <select id="updateStaffWorkingLength" parameterType="Staff">
    UPDATE crm.staffinfo SET `lengthofworking/minute` = (select temp.workinghour from (SELECT b.assignedstfid as staffid, SUM(b.duration) as workinghour FROM crm.bookingtable b, crm.staffinfo s where s.staffid = b.assignedstfid GROUP BY b.assignedstfid)as temp where temp.staffid = staffinfo.staffid);
    </select>

</mapper>
```

finally, in Class **StaffController.java**:

```
@RequestMapping("/stafflist")
    public String list(Model model){
        ss.updateStaffWorkingLength();  //here for update the column
        List<Staff> allStaffs = ss.getAllStaffs(); // here for retrieve the data from table 'staffinfo'
        model.addAttribute("allStaffs", allStaffs);
        return "staff/list";
    }
```

And I want to stress that **I have defined the 'list.html' in the 'staff' directory already.**

Now when I click the link '/stafflist', I get:

> Whitelabel Error Page
> This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Comment: I think you got the mapping wrong. What's the specific URL you are trying on the link? Can you try it in command line using CURL or WGET?

Answer (score 0):

In the main application class. Add " scanBasePackages= 'package with dao'

Example :

@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages={"com.usman.dao"})
public class SpringApplication() {

}

this shall work, Let me know.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).